# Why FormControlName copies value if under different FormGroup in FormArray

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

So I have a reactive form where I'm using certain FormGroup(Contact with first and last name) and adding those up in an FormArray. However every time I update value in one of the FormControls with obviously same name(firstName, lastName) value gets updated throughout the FormArray FormGroup FormControls.
What am I doing wrong?

```
contact = new FormGroup
  ({
    firstName: new FormControl(),
    lastName: new FormControl()
});

this.form = this.fb.group({
  name: ['', Validators.required],
  contacts: this.fb.array([
    this.contact
  ])
});
```

I would like to add as many contact FormGroups as needed to FormArray and keep their FormControlNames but have the Form value ultimately populated with unique corresponding values.

Comment: can you share template code?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you're adding the same formGroup instance to the formArray multiple times.
You need to create a new formGroup instance every time you add to the formArray:

```
export class ContactForm extends FormGroup{ 
        constructor(){
            super({
              firstName: new FormControl(),
              lastName: new FormControl(),
            });
     }
    }
```

then later:

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      contacts: this.fb.array([
        new ContactForm(),
      ])
    });
```